# Spring Aggregation Group

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

I did create an aggregate service as below

```
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
class Configuration {

@Autowired
Processor processor;


@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = Processor.INPUT)
@Bean
public MessageHandler aggregator() {

    AggregatingMessageHandler aggregatingMessageHandler =
            new AggregatingMessageHandler(new DefaultAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor(),
                    new SimpleMessageStore(10));

    //AggregatorFactoryBean aggregatorFactoryBean = new AggregatorFactoryBean();
    //aggregatorFactoryBean.setMessageStore();
    aggregatingMessageHandler.setOutputChannel(processor.output());
    //aggregatorFactoryBean.setDiscardChannel(processor.output());
    aggregatingMessageHandler.setSendPartialResultOnExpiry(true);
    aggregatingMessageHandler.setSendTimeout(1000L);
    aggregatingMessageHandler.setCorrelationStrategy(new  ExpressionEvaluatingCorrelationStrategy("requestType"));
    aggregatingMessageHandler.setReleaseStrategy(new MessageCountReleaseStrategy(3)); //ExpressionEvaluatingReleaseStrategy("size() == 5")
    aggregatingMessageHandler.setExpireGroupsUponCompletion(true);
    aggregatingMessageHandler.setGroupTimeoutExpression(new ValueExpression<>(3000L)); //size() ge 2 ? 5000 : -1
    aggregatingMessageHandler.setExpireGroupsUponTimeout(true);
    return aggregatingMessageHandler;
    }
}
```

Now i want to release the group as soon as a new group is created, so i only have one group at a time.

To be more specific i do receive two types of requests 'PUT' and 'DEL' . i want to keep aggregating per the above rules but as soon as i receive a request type other than what i am aggregating i want to release the current group and start aggregating the new Type.

The reason i want to do this is because these requests are sent to another party that don't support having PUT and DEL requests at the same time and i can't delay any DEL request as sequence between PUT and DEL is important.

I understand that i need to create a custom release Pojo but will i be able to check the current groups ?

For Example

If i receive 6 messages like below

> PUT    PUT    PUT     DEL     DEL    PUT

they should be aggregated as below

> 3PUT
>
> 2 DEL
>
> 1 PUT

Comment: Sorry, your question isn't clear. Having `CorrelationStrategy` as a `FOO` literal, you always end up with the same single group and all messages are aggregated only to this one. Nothing more. Fully unclear what should be the action around "release the group as soon as a new group is created".

Comment: @ArtemBilan sorry for the mistake , i did update the question hopefully it is clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up implementing the below `ReleaseStrategy` as i found it simpler than removing message and queuing it again.

```
class MessageCountAndOnlyOneGroupReleaseStrategy implements org.springframework.integration.aggregator.ReleaseStrategy {

    private final int threshold;

    private final MessageGroupProcessor messageGroupProcessor;


    public MessageCountAndOnlyOneGroupReleaseStrategy(int threshold,MessageGroupProcessor messageGroupProcessor) {
        super();
        this.threshold = threshold;
        this.messageGroupProcessor = messageGroupProcessor;
    }

    private MessageGroup currentGroup;

    @Override
    public boolean canRelease(MessageGroup group) {
        if(currentGroup == null)
            currentGroup = group;

        if(!group.getGroupId().equals(currentGroup.getGroupId())) {
            messageGroupProcessor.processMessageGroup(currentGroup);
            currentGroup = group;
            return false;
        }


        return group.size() >= this.threshold;
    }

}
```

Note that i did used `new HeaderAttributeCorrelationStrategy("request_type")` instead of just `FOO` for `CollorationStrategy`

Answer (score 0):

OK. Thank you for sharing more info.

Yes, you custom `ReleaseStrategy` can check that message type and return `true` to lead to the group completion function.

As long as you have only static `correlationKey`, so only one group is there in the store. When your message is stepping to the `ReleaseStrategy`, there won't be much magic just to check the current group for completion signal. Since there are no any other groups in the store, there is no need any complex release logic.

You should add `expireGroupsUponCompletion = true` to let the group to be removed after completion and the next message will form a new group for the same `correlationKey`.

**UPDATE**

Thank you for further info!

So, yes, your original PoC is good. And even static `correlationKey` is fine, since you are just going to collect incoming messages to batches.

Your custom `ReleaseStrategy` should analyze `MessageGroup` for a message with different `key` and return `true` in that case.

The custom `MessageGroupProcessor` should filter a message with different key from the output `List` and send that message to the aggregator back to let to form a new group for a sequence for its `key`.

Comment: Ok , so you suggest to keep the correlationKey static , and then check the method and when it change i do release right ?

Comment: No, the correlationKey is based on the splitter. See it's documentation and aggregator's as well. It isn't clear what is method in your context. And we also need to know how and what you would like to release

Comment: i have two types of messages 'PUT' and 'DEL' , i can use this field as correlationKey or keep it static . What i want to do is to release the group as soon as i receive a message that has different type , i updated the question with example

Comment: Please, find an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: i could not figure out how i should implement the MessageGroupProcessor . The last message should be sent back to aggregator as first in the new group

Comment: Correct, and removed from the output list because it isn't a part of the current group. Bear in mind you should send that in the separate thread otherwise there will be dead lock on the `lock.lockInterruptibly()`